# insert mysql query auto-increment

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to insert new incremental values with a query with phpmyadmin

```
INSERT INTO `ps_feature_shop`(`id_feature`, `id_shop`) VALUES ( '1', '1')
```

where `id_shop` is always 1 and `id_feature` should be incremental with specifics number that I will decide like from 1 to 1000 or from 2000 to 30000.

How do I do this?

Comment: if you're inserting values yourself, then you can't really use auto_increment - you'll have to generate those numbers yourself and make sure you don't cause any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do with in php code  this may help you

```
<?php
    $startValue=1;
    $endValue=1000;
    function insertValue($startValue,$endValue){
         for($i=$startValue;$i<=$endValue;$i++){
            INSERT INTO `ps_feature_shop`(`id_feature`, `id_shop`) VALUES ( $i, '1');
         }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the starting value of your AUTO_INCREMENT column with your CREATE TABLE statement or with an ALTER TABLE statement later, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html

I've never used it, but it seems you can globally specify the increment with the server option `auto_increment_increment`. But that value will apply to all tables on the server.
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment